# Want show only limited childeren of parent node in d3 sunburst chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have created 2 level sunburst chart on http://test.smokethis.com/wheel/ which is working perfectly.
But i want to validate my chart to show only 10 child of a particular parent and an additional node called "More child".
The behaviour on "More child" will be same as on click on parent. Which reveal all child of parent.

[Image link of current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJYgP.png)

[Image link of Resultant behaviour.Which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTyr.png)

```js
var d3Data = JSON.parse(jQuery('body .Jsondata').text())[0];

const m0 = {
  id: "123",
  variables: [
   
    {
      name: "chart",
      inputs: ["partition","data","d3","DOM","width","color","arc","format","radius"],
      value: (function(partition,data,d3,DOM,width,color,arc,format,radius)
{
var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");
var b = {
  w: 140, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
}; 
 

          
           const root = partition(data);

  root.each(d => d.current = d);

  const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(width, width))
      .style("width", "100%")
      .style("height", "auto")
      .style("font", "20px sans-serif");

  const g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${width / 2})`);

  const path = g.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", d => { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; console.log('d value--',d); return (typeof d.data.color != 'undefined' && d.data.color != '') ? d.data.color : color(d.data.name); })
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
      .attr("d", d => arc(d.current));

  path.filter(d => d.children)
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", clicked);

  path.append("title")
      .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join("/")}\n${format(d.value)}`);

  const label = g.append("g")
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("user-select", "none")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.current))
      .attr("transform", d => labelTransform(d.current))
      .text(d => d.data.name);

  const parent = g.append("circle")
      .datum(root)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
      .on("click", clicked);

  
 initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  return svg.node();
    
   
function clicked(p) {
   updateBreadcrumbs(getParents(p),p.value);
   var level = p.ancestors().map(p => p.data.name).reverse();
   
   // var str = '';
   // if(level.length > 1){
 // for(var i=0;i<level.length;i++){
  // str += '<span class="str_att show-pointer" style="background-color: #8cb125;margin-right:10px;border-radius: 5px;padding: 5px 10px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: #fff;font-weight: 700;">'+level[i]+'</a></span>';
 // }
   // }
   
   
   //jQuery('.breadCrumb').html(str);
   console.log('level-=-',level);
    parent.datum(p.parent || root);

    root.each(d => d.target = {
      x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
      x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
      y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
      y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
    });

    const t = g.transition().duration(750);
 //console.log('p',p);
    // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
    // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
    // the next transition from the desired position.
    path.transition(t)
        .tween("data", d => {
          const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
   
          return t => d.current = i(t);
        })
      .filter(function(d) {
        return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || arcVisible(d.target);
      })
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
        .attrTween("d", d => () => arc(d.current));

    label.filter(function(d) {
        return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || labelVisible(d.target);
      }).transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.target))
        .attrTween("transform", d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
  }
  function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select(".breadCrumb").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", width/10)
    .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {
  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
    .selectAll("g").on("click", clicked)
    .data(nodeArray, function(x) { return percentageString + x.data.name + x.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
    .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
    .style("fill", function(x) { return color(x.data.name); });

  entering.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
    .attr("y", b.h / 2)
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(x) { return x.data.name; });

  entering.attr("transform", function(x, i) { return "translate(" + i* (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)"; });


  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
    .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
    .attr("y", b.h / 2)
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
    .style("visibility", "");

}

function breadcrumbPoints(x, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

  function arcVisible(d) {
    return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
  }

  function labelVisible(d) {
    return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
  }

  function labelTransform(d) {
    const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
    const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
    return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
  }   
 
 function getParents(a){
  var nodeArray = [a];
  while(a.parent){
    nodeArray.push(a.parent);
    a = a.parent
  }
  return nodeArray.reverse();
}

 
}
)
    },
    {
      name: "data",
      value: (function(){
    return d3Data;
})
    },
    {
      name: "partition",
      inputs: ["d3"],
      value: (function(d3){
  //  console.log('partition',d3);
    return(
data => {
  const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
      .sum(d => d.size)
      .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
   console.log('data',d3.partition().size([2 * Math.PI, root.height+1])(root));
  return d3.partition()
      .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height+1])
    (root);
 

 
}
)

})
    },
    {
      name: "color",
      inputs: ["d3","data"],
      value: (function(d3,data){return (
d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1))
)})
    },
    {
      name: "format",
      inputs: ["d3"],
      value: (function(d3){return(
d3.format(",d")
)})
    },
    {
      name: "width",
      value: (function(){return(
932
)})
    },
    {
      name: "radius",
      inputs: ["width"],
      value: (function(width){return(
width / 6
)})
    },
    {
      name: "arc",
      inputs: ["d3","radius"],
      value: (function(d3,radius){return(
d3.arc()
    .startAngle(d => d.x0)
    .endAngle(d => d.x1)
    .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
    .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
    .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
    .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1))
)})
    },
    {
      name: "d3",
      inputs: ["require"],
      value: (function(require){return(
require("https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js")
)})
    }
  ]
};

const notebook = {
  id: "123",
  modules: [m0]
};


function loadData(){
   $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://shopnz.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_list_items&sunburst=sunburstcat',
    success: function(response){
     console.log('response',response[0]);
     console.log('data-=-=',data);
                                  data = response[0];
 
 }
   });
 
}
export default notebook;
```

```js
[{"name":"Balance","term_id":"588","slug":"balance","parent":"0","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Aroma","term_id":"589","slug":"aroma","parent":"588","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Earth","term_id":"593","slug":"earth","parent":"589","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Fruit","term_id":"594","slug":"fruit","parent":"589","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Herb","term_id":"595","slug":"herb","parent":"589","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Pungent","term_id":"596","slug":"pungent","parent":"589","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Spice","term_id":"597","slug":"spice","parent":"589","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"Health","term_id":"590","slug":"health","parent":"588","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Body","term_id":"598","slug":"body","parent":"590","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Fatigue","term_id":"613","slug":"fatigue","parent":"598","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Sleep","term_id":"616","slug":"sleep","parent":"613","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"PainRelief","term_id":"614","slug":"painrelief","parent":"598","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Spasms","term_id":"617","slug":"spasms","parent":"614","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Relaxed","term_id":"618","slug":"relaxed","parent":"614","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"Digestion","term_id":"615","slug":"digestion","parent":"598","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Appetite","term_id":"619","slug":"appetite","parent":"615","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Nausea","term_id":"620","slug":"nausea","parent":"615","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]}]},{"name":"Mind","term_id":"599","slug":"mind","parent":"590","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Behavior","term_id":"621","slug":"behavior","parent":"599","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Sedative","term_id":"623","slug":"sedative","parent":"621","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Energetic","term_id":"624","slug":"energetic","parent":"621","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Focus","term_id":"625","slug":"focus","parent":"621","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"Mood","term_id":"622","slug":"mood","parent":"599","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Creative","term_id":"626","slug":"creative","parent":"622","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Uplifted","term_id":"627","slug":"uplifted","parent":"622","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]}]}]},{"name":"Medical","term_id":"591","slug":"medical","parent":"588","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Condition","term_id":"600","slug":"condition","parent":"591","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Cancer","term_id":"602","slug":"cancer","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"PMS","term_id":"603","slug":"pms","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Arthritis","term_id":"628","slug":"arthritis","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Asthma","term_id":"629","slug":"asthma","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Cachexia","term_id":"630","slug":"cachexia","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Crohn\u2019s Disease","term_id":"631","slug":"crohns-disease","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Depression (currently a 'symptom')","term_id":"632","slug":"depression-currently-a-symptom","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Epilepsy","term_id":"633","slug":"epilepsy","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Gastrointestinal Disorder","term_id":"634","slug":"gastrointestinal-disorder","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Hypertension","term_id":"635","slug":"hypertension","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Parkinson\u2019s","term_id":"636","slug":"parkinsons","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Phantom Limb Pain","term_id":"637","slug":"phantom-limb-pain","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Spinal Cord Injury","term_id":"638","slug":"spinal-cord-injury","parent":"600","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"Symptom","term_id":"601","slug":"symptom","parent":"591","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Anxiety","term_id":"604","slug":"anxiety","parent":"601","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"ACDC","term_id":"612","slug":"acdc","parent":"604","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]},{"name":"Depresssion","term_id":"605","slug":"depresssion","parent":"601","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]}]},{"name":"Terpenes","term_id":"592","slug":"terpenes","parent":"588","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Humulene","term_id":"606","slug":"humulene","parent":"592","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Limonene","term_id":"607","slug":"limonene","parent":"592","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Linalool","term_id":"608","slug":"linalool","parent":"592","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Myrcene","term_id":"609","slug":"myrcene","parent":"592","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"},{"name":"Pinene","term_id":"610","slug":"pinene","parent":"592","has_children":true,"color":"#aac62d","children":[{"name":"Romulan","term_id":"611","slug":"romulan","parent":"610","has_children":false,"size":"1000","color":"#aac62d"}]}]}]}]
```

This is my data.